# Как сделать vector типа любого класса, который наследуется от абстрактного класса?

Tags: c++, vector

У меня есть абстрактный класс IReader

```
#ifndef GAME_IREADER_H
#define GAME_IREADER_H

class Wall;

class IReader{
    virtual std::vector<Wall> Read() = 0;
};

#endif //GAME_IREADER_H
```

Есть класс Wall, я хочу чтобы у меня vector в IReader был типа не Wall, а мог бы принимать значения любого класса, который наследуется от IReader

То есть в классе IReader

```
virtual std::vector<?> Read() = 0;
```

а в Wall.h, я мог бы написать так:

```
#ifndef GAME_WALL_H
#define GAME_WALL_H
#include "IReader.h"

class Wall : IReader {
private:
    int x;
    int y;
public:
    std::vector<класс_наследник_от_IReader> Read() override;

    int getX() const;

    int getY() const;
};


#endif //GAME_WALL_H
```

так же и в Wall.cpp

```
#include <vector>
#include "Wall.h"

std::vector<класс_наследник_от_IReader> Wall::Read() {
    std::vector<Wall> Walls;

    return Walls;
}

int Wall::getX() const {
    return x;
}

int Wall::getY() const {
    return y;
}
```

Comment: Беда в том, что если даже о классах Base и Derived можно сказать, что Derived является Base, то сказать того же о векторах этих объектов нельзя.

Comment: C++ является язяком со статической типизацией и "принимать значения любого класса" тип не может. Для этого нужен полиморфизм, статический (шаблон) или динамический (иерархия классов с хранением указателя на базовый).

Comment: @Harry как тогда можно задать произвольный тип для vector, чтобы можно было любой тип указать, а ля `vector<T>`, по аналогии с `List<T>` в Java?

Comment: я знаю ответ на Ваш вопрос. Но перед тем, как я его напишу, объясните, какую именно задачу Вы решаете. То, что приведено в вопросе - это просто попытка решить один маленький кусочек Вашей задачи.

Comment: @KoVadim Необходимо создать интерфейс для чтения информации с txt файла и реализовать его. По моей задумке считывать он будет некоторые координаты, присваивать их для класса `Wall`, и записывать потом каждую стену в `vector`, чтоб в другом методе их отобразить используя его.

Comment: ок, это все меняет. А не задумывались о том, что вектор, который торчит с класса не совсем интерфейс в классическом понимании? сделайте функции get/set и все будет ок. Кстати, если в базовом классе А get возвращает указатель на некий базовый класс B, то в наследнике A get может возвращать указатель на наследника B. И все, дело в шляпе

Comment: @KoVadim не совсем понял, что необходимо. Просто я с С++ только начинаю знакомиться, так сказать. Буквально пару месяцев пишу на нем. До этого Java, C# в основном.

Comment: а просто выкиньте с головы их. Да, в них есть ковариантность в стандартных контейнерах, но  там просто обман компилятора. В той же джаве на самом деле контейнер просто хранит указатели (да да, указатели, которые в джаве называется ссылками) и проблем нет.

думаю, Вы слишком джавовское решение делаете. Просто сделайте класс, у которого есть только функции ( в джаве называемые "методами") и все.

Comment: @KoVadim У меня есть четкое задание и в нем указано, что нужно сделать интерфейс

Comment: так никто же не запрещает. просто вектор не выносите. переменные класса, так называемые "поля" не являются частью интерфейса в классическом его понимании.

Comment: @KoVadim а у меня vector - это не поле, у метод типа vector. Посмотрите еще раз код в вопросе. А то что там равенство нулю, называют же чистой виртуальной функцией такое выражение.

Comment: ой, это я упустил. но даже в этом случае, это можно спрятать. Но теперь у меня к Вашему коду уже куча вопросов. класс Wall получается возвращает вектор объектов как он сам? Тогда покажите, как это все хотели бы использовать

Comment: @KoVadim мое упущение. Допилил класс WallsManager. А в Walls оставил только координаты. Я планирую, что в WallsManager у меня считываются координаты, и потом записывается новый экземпляр Wall в vector. и потом брать из него Wall получать геттерами x,y и отрисовывать.